# no instance of overloaded function "search" matches the argument list

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, reference

I have the following problem with my search function.
It expects 3 parameters, and one of them is something like const rational_t* v. I want to pass a vector through that parameter but it doesnt seems to work..

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include "rational_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

bool search(const rational_t* v, const int n, const rational_t& x)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(v[i].value() == x.value()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    rational_t a(1, 2), b(3), c, d(1, 2);
    vector<rational_t> v;

    v.push_back(a);
    v.push_back(b);
    v.push_back(c);

    cout << "a.value()= " << a.value() << endl;
    cout << "b.value()= " << b.value() << endl;
    cout << "c.value()= " << c.value() << endl;

    cout << search(v, v.size(), d); // Problem here

    return 0;
}
```

I´ve also tried cout << search(v&, v.size(), d); with the reference &.

Any ideas? Thank You.

The class :

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>

#define EPSILON 1e-6

using namespace std;

class rational_t
{
  int num_, den_;

public:
  rational_t(const int = 0, const int = 1);
  ~rational_t() {}

  int get_num() const
  {
    return num_;
  }

  int get_den() const
  {
    return den_;
  }

  void set_num(const int n)
  {
    num_ = n;
  }

  void set_den(const int d)
  {
    assert(d != 0), den_ = d;
  }

  double value(void) const;
  rational_t opposite(void) const;
  rational_t reciprocal(void) const;

  bool equal(const rational_t &r, const double precision = EPSILON) const;
  bool greater(const rational_t &r, const double precision = EPSILON) 
const;
  bool less(const rational_t &r, const double precision = EPSILON) const;
  bool cero_equal(const double precision) const;

  void write(ostream &os = cout) const;
  void read(istream &is = cin);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument of `search` should be a `rational_t*` but you're passing a `vector<rational_t>`.

You want

```
search(v.data(), v.size(), d)
```

instead of

```
search(v, v.size(), d)
```

---

But I'd write this like this which is cleaner IMO:

```
bool search(vector<rational_t> & v, const rational_t& x)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if (v[i].value() == x.value()) {
      return true;
    }
    else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

...
cout << search(v, d);
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. But i dont understand it.. Thats becouse the pointer or becouse without the .data it canno reach the content of the vector?

Comment: A `std::vector<Foo>` is not the same thing as a `Foo*`. But `std::vector<Foo>::data()` is, it returns the pointer to the first element of the vector.

Comment: Got it. Thank you!